# provide a streaming interface for a http service for downloading very large files

Tags: java, scala, stream, netty

We need to write some code to download very large files( > 8 GB) from a http server that support byte-range header.

The question is what is the right way to write a method and expose the download content as a stream?

is ChannelBufferOutputStream the right way to go? what if this is a unload scenario?

assume my method is something like :

```
def getDownloadStream(url :String): ChannelBufferOutPutStream
```

How do I manage the continuous streaming that comes from multiple http calls range by range?

What memory impact will this have?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to take a look at [PlayFramework](http://www.playframework.com/), which offer [`Iteratee`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Iteratees) to implement such use cases.

Comment: hmm, I am not sure I can use this package, just trying to get this one scenario( handle download of large data file) working.

Comment: if I just need some very basic implementation not based on any 3rd party framework etc. how does a sketch of that look like? I imagine it would be somehthing like : while not end=> fetch next block and write to output stream?